# SharePoint search Client Object Model and Server Side Object Model

Tags: search-results, object-model, people-search, visual-studio-2013, keywordquery

So I have two Console Search which I am testing out the usage of SharePoint Search Models via visual studio 2013.

I encountered an issue where EnablePhonetic and EnableNicknames does not really work within the Server Object Model but works perfectly fine for Client Object model.

```
The following is my Client Object Model:

        static void Main(string[] args)
                {
                    using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("http://portal.conium.com/sites/TestView/"))
                    {
                        Guid PeopleSearch= new Guid("b09a7990-05ea-4af9-81ef-edfab16c4e31");// this is the default people search source id

                        KeywordQuery keywordQuery = new KeywordQuery(clientContext);
                        keywordQuery.SourceId = PeopleSearch;
                        keywordQuery.EnableNicknames = true;
                        keywordQuery.EnablePhonetic = true; 
                        keywordQuery.RankingModelId = "D9BFB1A1-9036-4627-83B2-BBD9983AC8A1";//Default sharepoint People ranking model
                        keywordQuery.TrimDuplicates = false;
                        keywordQuery.QueryText = "Sps";
        SearchExecutor searchExecutor = new SearchExecutor(clientContext);


                        ClientResult<ResultTableCollection> results = searchExecutor.ExecuteQuery(keywordQuery);
                        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                            foreach (var resultRow in results.Value[0].ResultRows)
                            {Console.WriteLine("Path" + " : {0}", resultRow["Path"].ToString());}
```

It always returns all Sps users' mysite paths.

(Content,Search,Services,sites,mysite,farm) --> which is all I had made.

However in Server Object Model... it is inconsistent and returns results similarly or returns nothing. This is the code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                Guid PeopleSearch = new Guid("b09a7990-05ea-4af9-81ef-edfab16c4e31");
    using(SPSite site = new SPSite("http://portal.conium.com/sites/testSearch"))
                {
     KeywordQuery keywordQuery = new KeywordQuery(site);
                        keywordQuery.SourceId = PeopleSearch;
                        keywordQuery.EnableNicknames = true;
                        keywordQuery.EnablePhonetic = true;
                        keywordQuery.RankingModelId = "D9BFB1A1-9036-4627-83B2-BBD9983AC8A1";
                        keywordQuery.TrimDuplicates = false;
                        keywordQuery.QueryText = "Sps";
    SearchExecutor searchExecutor = new SearchExecutor();
                        ResultTableCollection resultTableCollection = searchExecutor.ExecuteQuery(keywordQuery);
                        var resultTables = resultTableCollection.Filter("TableType", KnownTableTypes.RelevantResults);
                        var resultTable = resultTables.FirstOrDefault();
    DataTable dataTable = resultTable.Table;
    for (int i = 0; i < rowCount;i++)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Path" + " : {0}",dataTable.Rows[i]["Path"].ToString());
                        }
                 }
           }
```

However, if I were to explictly search for people with their user name.

Example: `keywordQuery.querytext = "Sps Farm";`

It always works correctly for both Client and Server models.
I have tried other things  like IgnoreAllNoiseQuery=false, EnableStemming=true.

I am trying apply the server object model on a Web Part as a test for creating a search web part from scratch. It returns exactly like the console application for server object model.

Is there something wrong with the code?

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Have you tried just specifying the SourceID and not the RankingModelId?

Comment: Yeap.. It still happens. However I've tried in a webpart and it works after i set the query text to have ContentClass=urn:content-class:SPSPeople. I am not quite sure this is the correct method? Because the result sources has exactly that query attached behind to the searchterms. But temporarily it works.